# adding JRadioButton to RadioButton group

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, jradiobutton, buttongroup

Good day

Would like to know how to add radiobuttons to a ButtonGroup by dragging and dropping components on to the frame.

```
JRadioButton male = new JRadioButton("Male");
JRadioButton female = new JRadioButton("Female");
ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(male);
bg.add(female);
pane.add(male);
pane.add(female);
```

How can I do this by simple dragging and dropping. If I drop the ButtonGroup onto the frame it gets grouped under 'other components' and from there I am not exactly sure how to add radio buttons to the button group.

thanks
regards Arian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have look at [HierarchyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/HierarchyListener.html), on `hierarchyChanged` event you have add a new `JRadioButton` to the `ButtonGroup`, carefully with last know isSelected for concrete `JRadioButton`